# Serving static files in flask, output is the file name instead of it's contents

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to serve 2 static files named `index.html` and `main.js` in flask. My code is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def host_html():
    return url_for('static', filename='index.html')



@app.route('/map.js')
def host_map():
    return url_for('static', filename='map.js')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The output however on the web page is `/static/index.html`. What am I missing?

Comment: use `render_template()` for the HTML

Answer (score 1):

`url_for` function just returns a url, not the actual file. What you want to use in this case is `send_from_directory`: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.send_from_directory

In general, i guess what you really want to do, is to use `url_for` in i a jinja template, which you return by `render_template`.